# Why does the Windows Forms Designer cast int to byte then back to int for FromArgb?

Tags: c#, winforms, colors, designer

I was looking through some code today and saw something like the following:

```
var colour = Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(227)))), ((int)(((byte)(213)))), ((int)(((byte)(193)))));
```

When I asked why it was so, since Resharper confirmed that all the casts are redundant, I was told that the Designer done it that way and they had copied that.

I had a look and sure enough the Designer generates code the same as above when setting a property to a custom colour.

Does anyone know why the Designer would do this? It doesn't appear to make sense on the face of it, unless I am missing something?

Comment: You might be missing the happy story here.  As long as machines write code like this, you'll get to keep your job for a while.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This code is auto-generated by the code serializer built into the Winforms designer.  The guilty party here is the System.Drawing.ColorConverter class, the TypeConverter for Color.  The relevant code in its ConvertTo() method is:

```
   member = typeof(Color).GetMethod("FromArgb", new Type[] { typeof(int), typeof(int), typeof(int) });
   arguments = new object[] { color2.R, color2.G, color2.B };
```

The R, G and B properties return a byte.  So the code serializer first generates the integer literal and applies the (byte) cast to match the arguments type.  Then sees that FromArgb() accepts integer arguments so applies the (int) cast.

This is just maniacal machine generated code.  It only has to be correct, it doesn't have to be pretty.

Comment: This is what I was after, an explanation about why the designer generated code like this in the first place.

Answer (score 6):

There is no benefit. All it does is make the code hard to read.

This is preferable

```
var colour = Color.FromArgb(227, 213, 193);
```

or even the alpha channel version:

```
var colour = Color.FromArgb(255, 227, 213, 193);
```

As @Alexei Levenkov points out, perhaps the author was being cautious, but given the clear name of the method and its (well known) intended use, why would anyone use a value greater then 255 for any of the parameters?

Ref. [Color.FromArgb Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.fromargb.aspx)

Comment: +1. First cast to byte may be used to truncate values (if values would not be constants), but I can't see any reason for second cast.

Comment: You seem to think this code was written by a human.  It wasn't, Winforms designer code is written by a machine.  It only has to compile, being pretty isn't a requirement.

Comment: @Hans: when I read the question "I was told that the designer done it that way " made it sound like 'a' designer, not 'the' designer! I'm aware of what the Winforms designer is.

Comment: I had already changed the code to this before I asked the question, and talked to the programmer as well. I was amazed that after pasting this code in he didn't stop to think it might not be the best thing to do. I probably wasn't clear enough about that in the question though...